# How to refactor these variables so they are present in the entire class component? (React)

Tags: reactjs, refactoring

This is the code I have right now:

```
class QuoteDisplay extends React.Component {

  tweetOut() {
    const quote = this.props.quote;
    const author = this.props.author;
    window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + quote + ' - ' + author);
  }

  render(){
    const quote = this.props.quote;
    const author = this.props.author;
    const handleGetQuote = this.props.handleGetQuote;
    return (
      <div className='quoteDisplay'>
        <span className='quote'>{quote}</span>
        <span className='author'>-{author}</span>
        <br/>
        <button 
          className='btn btn-primary newQuote'
          onClick={handleGetQuote}>
          New Quote
        </button>
        <button 
          className='btn btn-primary tweet'
          onClick={this.tweetOut.bind(this)}
          >
          Tweet Out
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

As you can see, I repeat the snippet of code twice - once in tweetOut() and once in render():

```
const quote = this.props.quote;
const author = this.props.author;
```

Is there a way to refactor this code so I don't have to repeat myself? I tried declaring it at the beginning of the class component. Even creating a constructor for it, but those methods don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This values are necessary in function and in render as well, so I suggest you to use ES6 destructuring and do:

```
tweetOut() {
    const { quote, author } = this.props;
    window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + quote + ' - ' + author);
  }
```

the same way for code in render():

```
const {quote, author, handleGetQuote } = this.props;
```

Comment: Thanks for this ES6 style of refactoring. But still looks like I have to repeat that snippet of code in both methods (tweetOut and render) - I guess it's unavoidable?

Comment: according to existing logic, it's has to be in 2 places.